# Nlog keeps reloading config file even when autoReload option is "false"

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using NLog 4.0.1 and this is the code to write to the log

```
    public static void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info(message);
    }
```

And here is the NLog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="false"
      throwExceptions="false">

  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="File" 
            name="default"            
            layout="${longdate} ${message}"
            fileName="${basedir}/PDF_${shortdate}.log"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="default" minlevel="Info" /> <!-- cambie minlevel="Off" para apagar el log de ventas -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

In the log file I am still seeing many messages about "Reloading configuration in 1 ms" but they should not be there (as far as I understand)

What I am doing wrong or what is missing

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that another module of the same project was using also NLog with a different config file. Therefore this rule (*) was causing those others logger to also to write on my log file.

```
<logger name="*" writeTo="default" minlevel="Info" />
```

The solution was to use a name in the logger

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="false"
      throwExceptions="false">

  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="File" 
            name="PaymentDetailsTarget"            
            layout="${longdate} ${message}"
            fileName="${basedir}/PD_${shortdate}.log"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!-- Para apagar el log de ventas cambie minlevel="Off"  -->
    <logger name="PaymentDetailsLogger" writeTo="PaymentDetailsTarget" minlevel="Info" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And write to log like this:

```
    private static NLog.Logger PDlogger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("PaymentDetailsLogger");

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs an information message using NLOG
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to be logged</param>
    public static void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        PDlogger.Info(message);
    }
```